# Elasticsearch: How do I index thousands of files using mapping?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, indexing, mapping, metadata

I'm trying to build a search engine. I'm using Php with elasticsearch. 
Manually performing base64 encoding and indexing every file within the folder would not be possible. 
The files will be mostly be in Word or PDF format. I've added the code for my most recent attempt at achieving this but it didn't work.

```
<?php
    $dir_path="yellow";
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $client= Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()->build();
    if(is_dir($dir_path))
    {
        $files=opendir($dir_path);
        if($files)
        {
            while(($file_name= readdir($files))!== FALSE)
            {
                if($file_name!=="."&$file_name!=="..")
                {
        $params= [
        'index'=>'try',
        'type'=>'mytype',
        'body'=>[   
        'my_attachment' =>[
          "cv" => base64_encode(file_get_contents("$dir_path/$file_name"))  ]   ]
        ];

    $response= $client->index($params);
    echo $response;
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This code is returning 'Notice: Array to string conversion" error instead of generating a confirmation.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to see inside ES ? Remember that each ES document is only a JSON object with fields and values. If you know how to parse DOC/PDF files - just write a script, which reads files one by one and puts them into ES. "thousands" is nothing for ES

Comment: I'm trying to create a Search Engine that would search for given keywords within DOC or PDF files. So I need to store the content of all doc files of a given folder so that I may use ES to find which document certain keywords are present in. I'm using the mapper-attachments plugin of ES. I've added my code in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
'body'=>[   
        'my_attachment' =>[
          "cv" => base64_encode(file_get_contents("$dir_path/$file_name"))  ]   ]
```

with

```
'body' => [
    'my_attachment' => 
     base64_encode(file_get_contents("$dir_path/$file_name"))
]
```

Comment: It doesn't help. Thanks anyway!